# Grails: calling an action that uses withForm

Tags: forms, grails

I have a situation in which I need to reuse an action that has its functionality wrapped in a `withForm` closure.

Everything works well when submitting the form but when I try to reuse that action in another way I get redirect errors from my browser. Specifically, I need to redirect another action to it, possibly call it with `chain`, and I also want to call it from a hyperlink.

I'd really like to avoid creating a redundant action or having the `invalidToken` closure execute the same code.  I've tried to find some more details about how `withForm` works and find out what happens if no token is passed to the closure but the Googles have let me down.

Is this possible? Am I trying to make it do something it can't?

More info:

I have a user edit controller action. It is wrapped with the withForm closure. There are three different cases in which I need to call this controller to render the user edit page:

1. An admin enters the user's id into an input and clicks the form
   submit button (this form uses useToken). This needs to be secured
   and protected from duplicate form submission.
2. An admin selects a user to edit from a list of employees by clicking
   on the user's name (a hyperlink). Its possible I could turn this into a form submission with useToken and do some CSS styling to make it look like a link.
3. An admin creates a new user. When the user is successfully created
   the create controller redirects (or uses chain) to the edit
   controller. I can't find a work around for this, except to create a redundant controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. If anyone has some insight into other methods of solving this please contribute. I'm sure I'm not the only one that has had this problem.

The answer is due, in large part to @Sergio's response. It was far more simple than what I was thinking it would be. I created my edit action without  `withForm`then call it from another action that wraps the edit action in the `withForm`.

```
def editWT(Long uid, Long pid){
    withForm{
        edit(uid, pid)
    }
}

def edit(Long uid, Long pid){
    // Do lots of stuff to prep the data for rendering the view
}
```

This answer isn't innovative or ground-breaking but it works. I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is used in more than one place a controller action isn't the best place to put it. I suggest you to move that piece of code to a [service](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html) and call it from both actions.

Comment: I understand what you are saying about moving reusable functionality to services. I try to do that as much as possible when writing controllers. Unfortunately that won't solve the problem. In this case I need to load the form (the gsp file) in different ways with the same data from the same controller.

Comment: @CheddarMonkey Looking at your edit, it seems that you need to add som e control to your action to determine if you will wrap it withForm or not.

Comment: "some control" that space should not be there :-) One way that I can think is to send some attribute in the request and if it is present, don't wrap it with withForm.